# Generic interfaces and covariance

Tags: java, generics

the code below works fine:

```
public class ICopyableTest {

    private interface ICopyable<T extends ICopyable<? extends T>> {
        void copyFrom(T original);
    }

    private interface IVal<T> extends ICopyable<IVal<? extends T>> {
        T getV();
    }

    private static class Val<T> implements IVal<T> {
        private T v;

        public T getV() {
            return v;
        }

        public Val(final T v) {
            this.v = v;
        }

        @Override public void copyFrom(final IVal<? extends T> original) {
            v = original.getV();
        }
    }

    private static class StrVal extends Val<String> {
        public StrVal(final String v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Val<Object> o1 = new Val<>(new Object());
        Val<String> o2 = new Val<>("qwe");

        StrVal o3 = new StrVal("zxc");

        o1.copyFrom(o2); // that's the point
        o1.copyFrom(o3);

        o2.copyFrom(o3);
        o3.copyFrom(o2);

        Val<Object> toObj = (Val<Object>) (Val<?>) o2; // [1]
    }
}
```

Basically i have ICopyable interface with provides copying functionality, IVal which adds storage of value above, and two example classes which implement Val. The point of `<? extends T>` is to provide covariant argument to the CopyFrom method, so you could do `o1.copyFrom(o2)` etc.
So it all works fine i guess.

Now let's say i want to have another parameterized over ICopyable or IVal class:

```
private static class Bla<T extends ICopyable<T>> {
    final T value1;
    final T value2;

    public Bla(final T value1, final T value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    void letsCopy() {
        value1.copyFrom(value2);
        value2.copyFrom(value1);
    }
}
```

Now why can't i instantiate it with any of the following?

```
new Bla<StrVal>(o3, o3);
new Bla<Val<Object>>(o1, o1);
new Bla<Val<String>>(o2, o2);
```

To be honest i'm a bit lost here myself and that's why i'm exploring it. There's a separate very important question of why working with generics is SO draining, when even after 5+ years working with java i can't figure out those things without half an hour meditation - am i just dumb?

I just want to have a parameterized class which will allow me to work with IVal/ICopyable values, note that it should be parameterized class, not individual method, so you can store the instances of those values in fields, for example.

Comment: Reading this was confusing. I think you are over complicating what you are trying to do. What in the simplest form are you trying to accomplish, whats your abstract goal/idea?

Comment: My end goal is pretty much what i wrote in the last paragraph, so implementing the Bla class in the correct way. In the example that class isn't doing anything too practical of course, but that's just an example - it's just a general "processing" class, it should receive IVal<String> or IVal<Object> for example and do something with them(letsCopy method for example). Sorry it's confusing, i can't understand the unrelying issue so i don't know how to ask the right question, i guess. I would be happy if someone can explain me why can't i instantiate Bla like that...

Comment: Hey @Underbalanced sorry if i upset you in any way, but imo there was no reason to delete your answer :-/

Comment: I am not. Just is not an answer and should not be left up because it doesn't satisfy what you are looking for. I have a system at home which does have a parameter holder using a a Object Array but I am not home. Also not at home to test your code. I just wrote my answer in a notepad :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done that this way

```
public class Test {

    interface Copyable<T> {
        void copyFrom(Copyable<T> v);
        T getV();
    }

    interface Val<T> extends Copyable<T> {
        // Do not know if this is usefull
    }

    abstract class AbstractVal<T> implements Val<T> {
        T value;
        public AbstractVal(T val) {
            this.value = val;
        }
    }

    class StrVal extends AbstractVal<String> {

        public StrVal(String o3) {
            super(o3);
        }

        @Override
        public void copyFrom(Copyable<String> v) {
            this.value = v.getV();
        }

        @Override
        public String getV() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    class Bla<T extends AbstractVal<S>, S> {
        final T value1;
        final T value2;

        public Bla( T value1,  final T value2) {
            this.value1 = value1;
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

        void letsCopy() {
            value1.copyFrom(value2);
        }
    }

    void test() {
        StrVal o1 = new StrVal("qwe");
        StrVal o2 = new StrVal("qwe2");
        StrVal o3 = new StrVal("zxc");
        Bla tester = new Bla<StrVal, String>(o1, o2);
        tester.letsCopy();
        System.out.println(tester.value1.getV());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.test();
    }
}
```

Maybe a little complicated for what it's doing but I think it's the idea..

Comment: That's interesting, so the trick `<T extends AbstractVal<S>, S>` with explicitly defining S actually works, in your code and in mine too. Thanks a lot for your answer, i'll try to work with that. Do you know if there's any other way you can express that, it just doesn't fell right, isn't it?